# how to know values at the same index in 2 lists in python are the same in positive or negative?

Tags: python

2 lists with same length, all are either float or int type, positive or negative, no possibility to be zero. I only want to know if all values in the same index has the same direction(positive or negative). Here is the logic, any better way to do it?

```
def same_direction(list1, list2):
    diff = []
    for i in len(list1):
        if (list1[i] > 0 and list2[i] > 0) or (list1[i]< 0 and list2[i] < 0):
            pass
        else:
            diff.append(i)
    if diff:
        return False
    return True

same_direction([1, 2, 3], [3, 7, 9]) True
same_direction([-1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]) False
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) the lists to pair the numbers and for each pair check if they have the same sign. Wrap above with [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#all) which terminates as soon as `False` value is found:

```
def same_direction(l1, l2):
    return all((x > 0) == (y > 0) for x, y in zip(l1, l2))

print(same_direction([1, 2, 3], [3, 7, 9]))
print(same_direction([-1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]))
print(same_direction([-1, 2, 3], [-1, 2, 3]))
```

Output:

```
True
False
True
```

Alternatively you could multiply the pairs and check if the result is greater than 0:

```
def same_direction(l1, l2):
    return all(x * y > 0 for x, y in zip(l1, l2))
```

Comment: I agree with `zip`/`all`, but wouldn't `(x>0) == (y>0)` be more obvious than the multiply?

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: @Robᵩ On the second thought I agree with you, works better with large ints as well. Changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: It took me a while to understand the beauty of the logic of `(x>0) == (y>0)`.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from your code, you can save a bit by short-circuiting and using xor

```
def same_direction(list1, list2):

    for i in len(list1):
        if (list1[i] > 0) ^ (list2[i] > 0):
            return False
    return True
```

Python purists will tell you that one should avoid indexing

```
def same_direction(list1, list2):

    for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2):
        if (l1 > 0) ^ (l2 > 0):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: `xor`, I never used it, great!

Comment: Yeah, although it reinvents `all`, I can't help but love this use of bitwise xor.

Comment: Gang, @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't see how it relates to `all` but on booleans it is the same as `!=` it just looks cooler ;-)

Comment: @PaulPanzer WRT `all`, your function could be re-written as `all((l1 > 0) ^ (l2 > 0) for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ah, ok, they can be used together. I thought you were suggesting one could somehow replace the other. Those little generator tricks seem popular on SO...